# Create custom url links in code igniter

Tags: mysql

I have searched all over the internet for information that would help me achieve this seemingly simple thing.

But I can't get my hands on any that is helpful.

What I want to do is to create a custom **url link** like `http://mywebsite.com/users/username`,

where

1) **'users'** is a MySQL table name

2) **'username'** is a column name.

I did some digging on the internet and found this code on github:

```
<?php
  //check for referal links
  function referal()
  {
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $cookie_value_set = $CI->input->cookie('_tm_ref', TRUE) ? $CI->input->cookie('_tm_ref', TRUE) : '';
  if ($CI->input->get('ref', TRUE) AND $cookie_value_set == '') {
    // referred user so set cookie to ref=username
     $cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'ref',
    'value'  => $CI->input->get('ref', TRUE),
    'expire' => '7776000',
  );
    $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    return TRUE;
   }elseif ($cookie_value_set == '') {
     $cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'ref',
    'value'  => 'sso',
    'expire' => '15552000',
  );
    $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    return TRUE;

   }elseif ($cookie_value_set != '') {
     //already referred so ignore
    return TRUE;

   }else{
      return TRUE;
   }
  }
//end of hooks file
?>
```

The owner of the gist only mentioned saving the file as referral.php inside the **hook** folder. This is not helping me with what I want to achieve, I don't know how to use the code:
1. How do I pass the **referrer** field to the variable **username** from the **users** table?
2. How do I load the hook file to view (register.php)?
3. How and where do I call the hook file?

So can anybody give me an insight?

Comment: Do you want the URI to build a database query? What's the usage plan etc?

Comment: Is this specifically for CodeIgniter (like in the title but not question), or just in general?  Can you post what you have tried so far to get this working?  If it is just for CodeIgniter, you should look into how their routing actually works: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html